# Generate Next app via command is missing modules

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I am trying to generate a new next app in my monorepo.

I tried using `nx console` extension from vs code.

I can generate new `react` app. It doesn't have any error. But when I try to generate a new `next` app. Its giving me this error.

> Cannot find module 'nx/src/utils/code-frames'

So I avoid using the extension and try to generate a new one by nx command.
[Link to nx doc](https://nx.dev/packages/next/generators/application)

Initially I tried to run this command `yarn nx g app myapp --directory`. I add yarn at front because I don't install nx globally

Here is what appear

[image]

as you can see I cannot generate next app.

So I search google and someone suggest that my package.json doesn't have `@nrwl/next` package. So I **install** the package and when I try again `yarn nx g app myapp --directory="testing"`, it ask me to choose the `stylesheet` type. I select `scss`

Then this error comes again

> Cannot find module 'nx/src/utils/code-frames'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your version of `@nrwl/next` matches the version of `nx` in your `package.json`.

So if you have installed `nx@15.3.0`, then you should also install `@nrwl/next@15.3.0`.

See https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/15168#issuecomment-1442049438 for more details.